# How to use the windows over function PySpark with time period constraint and other conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can I get some help on how to write this logic up in pyspark?

Suppose I have the the table as attached image shown.

So given: date, userid, visit, grouping (old) as inputs, I want to create a new column called grouping (new) such that it does the following:

for any given user id:

1. first check and see what's the grouping (old). If it is != Bad, then grouping (New) = grouping (old)
2. If the grouping (old) = Bad, then apply the most recent date's most recent visit's grouping (old) such that it is != Bad
3. However, if the most recent grouping (old) from a prior date that is != Bad is more than 30 days away, then make grouping (new) = Bad (as the data is out of date)

[image]

what I've attempted which didn't work as expected:

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400 

user_30d_tracker = 
  Window.partitionBy("userid")
    .orderBy(f.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(-days(30), 0)
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)


df = (df.withColumn("Grouping(old)_YN",
      f.when(f.col("Grouping(old)")==f.lit("Bad"), "No")
       .otherwise(f.lit("Yes"))))

df = df.withColumn("Grouping_new", 
          f.max(f.when(f.col("Grouping(old)_YN") == f.lit("Yes"), 
          f.col("Grouping(old)"))).over(user_30d_tracker))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose this is what your dataframe looks like

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [[123, "20200101", 1, "Good_sub1"],
        [123, "20200101", 2, "Bad"],
        [123, "20200115", 1, "Bad"],
        [123, "20200115", 2, "Bad"],
        [123, "20200116", 1, "Good_sub2"],
        [123, "20200116", 2, "Bad"],
        [123, "20200116", 3, "Good_sub3"],
        [123, "20220901", 1, "Bad"]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, 
                           "userid:int, date:string, visit:int, `grouping(old)`:string")
df.show()
# +------+--------+-----+-------------+
# |userid|    date|visit|grouping(old)|
# +------+--------+-----+-------------+
# |   123|20200101|    1|    Good_sub1|
# |   123|20200101|    2|          Bad|
# |   123|20200115|    1|          Bad|
# |   123|20200115|    2|          Bad|
# |   123|20200116|    1|    Good_sub2|
# |   123|20200116|    2|          Bad|
# |   123|20200116|    3|    Good_sub3|
# |   123|20220901|    1|          Bad|
# +------+--------+-----+-------------+

days = lambda i: i * 86400 

user_30d_tracker = Window.partitionBy("userid")\
                         .orderBy(f.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))\
                         .rangeBetween(-days(30), 0)\
                         .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)
```

Let's take a look at the `user_30d_tracker` window. This window needs some changes considering the points below

1. The order of the window seems to need the values of `visit` column beside the unix timestamp of `date`. With only timestamp of `date` in the `orderBy` clause, spark will not guarantee the rows with visit = 1 will come before visit = 2 for example. So, somehow we need to include `visit` column in the `orderBy` clause.
2. Additional frame `rowsBetween` will overwrite the `rangeBetween` frame, hence it will be different from what were expected.

An option would be only using `rangeBetween` frame for the window. But, since `rangeBetween` frame only allows 1 column to be used in `orderBy` expression, we can use a workaround by adding `visit` value to the unix timestamp of `date` (this is like treating `visit` as how many seconds had passed since `date` started).

```
user_30d_tracker =  Window\
                        .partitionBy("userid")\
                        .orderBy(f.unix_timestamp("date", "yyyyMMdd") + f.col("visit"))\
                        .rangeBetween(-days(30), 0)
```

Then, to get the most recent non-'Bad' grouping(old) value, it would be better using `last` function (with `ignorenulls=True`) instead of `max` since it takes the recent value in the window, not the maximum of sorted strings. After that, use `coalesce` to fill the null values in the new column.

```
df = (df
      .withColumn("Grouping(old)_YN",
                  f.when(f.col("Grouping(old)") == f.lit("Bad"), "No")
                  .otherwise(f.lit("Yes")))
      .withColumn("Grouping_new", 
                  f.last(f.when(f.col("Grouping(old)_YN") == f.lit("Yes"), 
                                f.col("Grouping(old)")), ignorenulls=True).over(user_30d_tracker))
      .withColumn("Grouping_new", f.coalesce(f.col("Grouping_new"), f.col("Grouping(old)")))
      )
df.show()

# +------+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+------------+
# |userid|    date|visit|grouping(old)|Grouping(old)_YN|Grouping_new|
# +------+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+------------+
# |   123|20200101|    1|    Good_sub1|             Yes|   Good_sub1|
# |   123|20200101|    2|          Bad|              No|   Good_sub1|
# |   123|20200115|    1|          Bad|              No|   Good_sub1|
# |   123|20200115|    2|          Bad|              No|   Good_sub1|
# |   123|20200116|    1|    Good_sub2|             Yes|   Good_sub2|
# |   123|20200116|    2|          Bad|              No|   Good_sub2|
# |   123|20200116|    3|    Good_sub3|             Yes|   Good_sub3|
# |   123|20220901|    1|          Bad|              No|         Bad|
# +------+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+------------+
```